# Scalable architecture design for social networking apps

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, mean-stack, social-networking, mern

I want to design and architect a scalable app that will be a combination of a social blog with all admin and blogging features plus the app will also have course broadcasting like coursera and udemy.

What technologies should I look into:
I have studied some LAMP and MEAN stack based apps but got more confused in choosing the tech stack.
should I use a standard solution like BuddyPress or some other WordPress based stuff or should I design it from scratch?
How do I divide it component wise so that's it scalable and highly modular?

Are there any references or some pre-made solutions or documentations or design patterns because whatever I am planning to work has already been done.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you wanna achieve.

For example, you have these ways for architecture:

1. A whole APP in one server.
2. Microservices, distributed parts of your app.
3. Serverless (Backend as service).

About apps, you already said it:

- If you choose to create something from scratch, you can control the architecture and services that your app need in order to work at 100%.
- If you choose APPs like Wordpress, Vanilla Forums and similar (APPs that you will have to install that you didn't create and perhaps you will end creating modules that solve problems that you have).

What else?

- Do you have time to create something from scratch?
- Do you have the money to create something from scratch?
- Does premade software like Wordpress fulfill all your requirements?

To be honest, if you have the money and time you can choose whatever you want.

But if time is important, well, choose something premade like Wordpress and similar solutions.

Once you answer those questions we will be able to help you with more details.